# How can I set the color of the selected text in code editor window in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, background-color

I would like Visual Studio 2010 to color a piece of selected text in the code editor window.

What I have done now is that: I open a file in VS 2010, and go to the piece of code which I am interested in by the following code:

```
EnvDTE80.DTE2 dte2;
dte2 = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
dte2.MainWindow.Activate();
EnvDTE.Window w = dte2.ItemOperations.OpenFile(filepath, EnvDTE.Constants.vsViewKindTextView);

EnvDTE.TextSelection textSelection = (EnvDTE.TextSelection)dte2.ActiveDocument.Selection;
textSelection.GotoLine(startRow, true);
```

Next, what I really want is to highlight the selected text with colors and backgrounds.

I have the following information: `(int)startRow`, `(int)startCol`, `(int)endRow` and `(int)endCol`. And the selected text ranges from `[startRow, startCol]` to `[endRow, endCol]`.

Comment: C# is my programming language.